# How can we reverse search for a particular command in terminal/Rshell and then go the immediate previous serach (not the previous of searched string)?

Tags: linux, terminal

The title of the question is not that clear. I want to do the following without explicitly opening the history:

Suppose I executed the following commands:

```
echo "hello1"
echo "hi"
echo "hi2"
echo "hello2"
echo "hi3"
echo "hi4"
echo "hi5"
```

Since we do a lot of operations, we sometimes forget the relevant string to grep.
If I do CTRL+R, search `hello` and press CTRL R, it will lead me to `hello2` then `hello1`

I want to go to `hi2` with the help of `hello2`. Something like:

`hello` in CTRL+R, which will lead me to `echo hello2` command and with the help of that go to `echo hi2` (the operation just before it) by some means
Is it possible to do this?

(want to do this for Rshell but I guess it should work same as terminal)